# Expect Script to SCP a File to Remote System

Tags: expect

I am a newbie at scripting and simply trying to utilize scp within a script to move a file to a remote system. I keep encountering errors within my code/or nothing happens/the file does not get copied.

I attempted multiple scripts but I feel I'm just not quite getting the language. In the code I've included, I am trying to scp the test.txt file to the remote system. I've also tried including a send "scp test.txt ${user}@XXXXXXXX.com" line as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set user "XXXXXX"
set password "XXXXXX"

log_file XXXX.txt

spawn /usr/bin/scp -f test.txt ${user}@XXXXXXXXXXX.com

expect "*assword"
send "${password}\n"
interact
```

I believe the file should be copied to the remote server but when I attempt to display it with ls -l I get nothing.

Comment: Why are you using expect / interactive passwords at all? Can't you just set up a public/private key pair?

Comment: Melpomene, this is part of an intro bash script course. The instructor is simply showing a few of the expect basics. I agree, a public/private key pair would be more secure.

Comment: Why would an intro bash script course use expect? I know a thing or two about bash scripting, but I've never used expect, ever. I question the design of this course.